# "Unresolved Reference" when trying to create new variable on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried making a new variable DF and python thinks it needs a reference. I am quite new to python so feel free to correct me if I am wrong or not using the correct vocabulary.

Things I have tried,
I have tried adding source root in PythonPath

---

```
import pandas as pd

import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'cQsW-yqpYm1ufuRgKqXe'

df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low','Adj. Close']]
#    ^ here lies the error where I recieve "Unresolved Reference"

print(df.head())
```

Error message:

> File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/untitled8/try.py", line 7, in
>   
>       df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low','Adj. Close']] NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: NVM I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

In the script you provide, `df` is never defined before that line, so python doesn't know how to interpret the expression `df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low','Adj. Close']]`.

I presume you mean dataframe in each instance you use "DF" in your post. In that case, you need to either create the dataframe yourself or import it from somewhere else before attempting to use a sub-set of it (which is what that line is attempting to do).